# Flutter compile modifying too many files

Tags: flutter

After a simple debug, so many files are modified.

This is the print before debug:
[image: This is the print before debug]

This is the print after debug:
[image: This is the print after debug]

It happens in both platforms (iOS and Android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build folder is refreshed everytime you compile your app so all the changes that happen within it are shown here.

You can add a .gitignore to your build folder so these files won't be included in git. **You generally don't need to back up/commit this folder** as it will be created/refreshed every time you compile the app.

You can either add the whole folder to the main gitignore file or just use the command `$ touch .gitignore` inside your build folder with `*` as the content of the file.

If you're using VSCode I would recommend the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension which let's you (among other things) directly ignore a folder within VSCode.

Comment: Ok, but that's weird.. I was working in another project and it wasn't happening. Btw, i added ".build/" to .gitignore and didn't work.

Comment: I think you need to add it as `/build` or `./build`, I can't try it out myself right now. Edit: I tried it out with an example repo, it works for me if i have a folder called "test" in the root of my repo, and add "/test" to my gitignore file.

Comment: Added another way to exclude the folder in my updated answer.

Comment: yeah that worked. i don't know why, but this project started withou gitnignore in the root. it has gitignore in ios and android folder